# Python Pandas custom datetime formats' font size in Excel output

Tags: python, excel, pandas

The `datetime_format` parameter of `pd.ExcelWriter` in Pandas is nice to format your datetime output pretty easy before using `to_excel()`; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898839/python-pandas-custom-time-format-in-excel-output) and the answer of jmcnamara, answered Sep 18 '14 at 22:23.

All format settings that are made afterwards are neglected, which is described in [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_pandas.html) in the section *Formatting of the Dataframe output* as well.

I have two questions:

1. Can I change the font_size of a datetime column that easy as well? Or do I have to take the way through `xlswriter` and write out the raw data?
2. Where is the documentation of `pd.ExcelWriter()`? Shouldn't there be a description which tells you which parameters you can use? I'm just finding a documentation of `to_excel()`; see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

Thanks!

Comment: You could [read the `ExcelWriter` code](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/6c692aee6d411d67997c4fadd023a1d4b7f91c12/pandas/io/excel.py#L550).

Comment: I think lines 550-573 make pretty clear, that it is not possible to change the font size that easy. There is no parameter ...

Comment: Agreed. I think the answers are __(1)__ you will need to subclass the `pandas` class and handle fonts yourself (see [`openpyxl` styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/styles.html)) and __(2)__ rely on the docstring I linked to above as your documentation for `ExcelWriter`.