# Format a column for excel date format from Format to Date within python script

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

```
df.to_excel(filename, index = False)
```

This is my current code for exporting data frame to an excel, column index 0 and 2 contain dates, but I need these columns to be formatted as an Excel date format. I have read online but I don't understand how to achieve this.

Can someone please explain

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(testing.xlsx",  datetime_format='dd/mm/yyyy')

hold.to_excel(writer, "Sheet1", index = False)

writer.close()
print("done")
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas custom time format in Excel output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898839/python-pandas-custom-time-format-in-excel-output)

Comment: How would you use the answer to target columns 0 and 2 only?

Comment: They apply to all dates

Comment: I couldn't make this work, do you think you could show me a working example?

Comment: What did you try and what did you get

Comment: I have added the code in my original post. It does not format the date time variables to a suitable instance in my excel file

Comment: @George Boast can you add a sample dataframe (hold) to your example. In the link in the comment above there is a similar example where the formatting clearly works. If it doesn’t work for you it may be that the dates aren’t in datetime format.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of data frame hold, with confidential data X out